# Syntax Error near ScanID

Tags: sqlite, foreign-key-relationship

Evening all

I have been working on a small application but kind of stuck at the SQLite foreign key constraint. Basically what i have is one "HostLookuptable" as

```
CREATE TABLE tblHostLookup ( 
HostID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
HostName TEXT);
```

And one "ScanLookuptable" as

```
CREATE TABLE tblScanLookup ( 
ScanID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
ScanDate TEXT);
```

Then there is another table that will have mapping between two tables as "ScanHistorytable"

```
CREATE TABLE tblScanHistory (
ScanHistoryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
HostID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(HostID) REFERENCES tblHostLookup(HostID),
ScanID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(ScanID) REFERENCES tblScanLookup(ScanID));
```

But i keep getting an error saying

```
Syntax error near ScanID
```

Why so? Are we not allowed to have more than one foreign key in a table? Any help in this regard would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If it's a foreign key limit, then try removing the HostID foreign key and see what happens.

Comment: @MarcB It works with one foreign key perfectly...but we seriously are not allowed to have more than one foreign key?

Comment: Don't see anything mentioned about limits on number of FK's (http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), so perhaps start looking if there's any invisible chars in there that could be causing a parse error, e.g. after the first HostID foreign key line. try retyping the whole create query over again.

Comment: @MarcB No..it's not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix table columns and table constraints; the constraints must be listed after all the columns:

```
CREATE TABLE tblScanHistory (
    ScanHistoryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    HostID INTEGER,
    ScanID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(HostID) REFERENCES tblHostLookup(HostID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ScanID) REFERENCES tblScanLookup(ScanID)
);
```

Or, simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE tblScanHistory (
    ScanHistoryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    HostID INTEGER REFERENCES tblHostLookup(HostID),
    ScanID INTEGER REFERENCES tblScanLookup(ScanID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks alot man...it worked! strange though i thought every column should remain with its foreign key...nevertheless thanks for clearing it

Comment: In the second form, the FKs *do* remain with their columns. To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Thanks for the help man...don't bother about the other question i solved it myself